# In app Subscriptions not working with different package names

Tags: android

So I have had subscriptions work in the past but ever since I added new environments that had different package names, it has stopped working. I'm unable to receive any Inventory when calling `queryInventoryAsync()`

My app's package name is: `com.myapp.trees` and this is the release package name.

I also created different two other environments: qa and staging and via gradle, I made it so that it adds this to the package name.

QA will have a package name: `com.myapp.trees.qa` while Staging has `com.myapp.trees.staging`.

I did a lot of debugging and I came to a point that when I arrive at the call to get a `Bundle skuDetails` via calling `getSkuDetails()`, I'm getting a response code of 5 which is developer error. The only thing I can really think of being the issue is the package names. In the google developer console, I can see all my subscriptions and I was wondering if I'm supposed to be handling it somehow by adding more subscription plans with a `qa` and `staging` counterpart?

Comment: Right, subscriptions are associated with individual apps. I think you have to upload an app for both `qa` and `staging`.

Answer (score 0):

SKUdetails are associated with the app's package name. You will have to create new subscriptions for the `staging` and `qa` counterparts. Apart from that, you will have to create a release in a closed track and add your tester user to the list of testers of that track. I'd say if you can avoid creating those counterparts and use just one, you are going to avoid a lot of configuration and potential issues.

I wrote a more extensive [guide](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/google-play-store) on how to configure the testing devices for the Google Play Billing just in case you want to check it out.

Comment: You mentioned creating a release in a closed track. Do you mean creating a release of the `staging` and `qa` apks? The issue I'm having with avoiding these counterparts is that I want to be able to maintain separate firebase projects for each flavor so I can track analytics and crashes. Not sure how I can separate it with just build types